# Как задать прототип с помощью объектной нотации?

Tags: javascript, наследование, prototype

есть конструктор, например

```
function Person(name, age){
            this.name = name || '';
            this.age = age || null;
        }
```

и несколько объектов, созданных с помощью Person, например

```
var ivan = new Person('Ivan', 25);
```

есть необходимость добавить методы в конструктор, например, приветствие и прощание

```
Person.prototype.greet = function (name){console.log('Hello, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);};
Person.prototype.bye = function (name){console.log('Bye, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);};
```

и они работают

```
ivan.greet('Pavel');    //Hello, Pavel, from Ivan
ivan.bye('Pavel');    //Bye, Pavel, from Ivan
```

однако, если я пытаюсь добавить эти методы с помощью объектной нотации

```
Person.prototype = {
    greet: function (name){console.log('Hello, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);},
    bye: function (name){console.log('Bye, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);}
}
```

то я получаю не то, что жду

```
ivan.greet('Pavel');    //undefined
ivan.bye('Pavel');    //undefined
```

Как сделать, чтобы работало? :)

Comment: Происходит это из-за того, что в JS объекты передаются по ссылке. `Person.prototype` можно назвать ссылкой на объект. Используя эту ссылку объект можно в последствии всяческим образом изменять. Но если выполнить операцию `Person.prototype = { foo: 'bar' }`, то ссылка `Person.prototype` теперь будет ссылаться на новый только что созданный объект `{ foo: 'bar' }`. Т.е. изменена в данном случае была только ссылка, оригинальный объект прототипа остался неизменным, а созданные инстансы класса продолжают использовать оригинальный объект, в котором `foo` как не было так и нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть два вариянта:

1. Создать `Person` объекты после добавления методов:

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name || '';
  this.age = age || null;
}

Person.prototype = {
  greet: function(name) {
    console.log('Hello, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);
  },
  bye: function(name) {
    console.log('Bye, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);
  }
};


var ivan = new Person('Ivan', 25);
ivan.greet("Pavel");
ivan.bye("Pavel");
```

2. Добавить методы в цикле:

```js
function Person(name, age) {
  this.name = name || '';
  this.age = age || null;
}

var ivan = new Person('Ivan', 25);

var personProto = {
  greet: function(name) {
    console.log('Hello, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);
  },
  bye: function(name) {
    console.log('Bye, ' + name + ', from ' + this.name);
  }
};

for(var i in personProto) {
  Person.prototype[i] = personProto[i];
}

ivan.greet("Pavel");
ivan.bye("Pavel");
```